# Importing a gziped csv into pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

I have an url: https://api.kite.trade/instruments

And this is my code to fetched data from url and write into excel

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://api.kite.trade/instruments"
df = pd.read_json(url)
df.to_excel("file.xlsx")
print("Program executed successfully")
```

but, when I run this program I'm getting error like this_

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_json' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a json, it's csv. So you need to use `read_csv`. Can you please try this?

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://api.kite.trade/instruments"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.to_excel("file.xlsx",index=False)
print("Program excuted successfully")
```

Comment: Show this error AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: If yes, Try downloading the csv to your desktop and rename it to another name, like my_csv.csv. Looks like pandas is being confused about what to import.

Comment: mean pip install csv

Comment: No, install this one and put to the same directory: "https://api.kite.trade/instruments"

Comment: sir when i Download the file from url and check the file extension it show no file extension...

Comment: I don't know why. It seems as csv in me.

Comment: Sir when I check the documentation there they write this "Retrieving the full instrument list¶
Unlike the rest of the calls that return JSON, the instrument list API returns a gzipped CSV dump of instruments across all exchanges that can be imported into a database."

Answer (score 0):

I added an example how I converted the text to a csv dump on your local drive.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.kite.trade/instruments"
filename = 'test.csv'

f = open(filename, 'w')
response = requests.get(url)
f.write(response.text)
```